# VisualBasic- How to tell a Log to make a new line? ^^

Tags: vb.net, vba

So I made a TextBox and I want to display a small test log in there.
I told my button to print a Test Text there whenever it gets pressed:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Button1Click As Boolean
    TextBox2.Text = Random()
    Button1Click = True
    If Button1Click Then
        TextBox1.Text = ("Generated ID:" & Random())
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "LELELELELLE"
    End If
    Button1Click = False
End Sub
```

The function Random just prints some random numbers there. Ofc it is working and it prints out that: GeneratedID: asd293r04orwr04fjdl BUT the Random numbers always get generated new IN THAT LINE. I want the button to add new lines whenever it is pressed so it looks like that:

1. GeneratedID: asd293r04orwr04fjdl
2. GeneratedID: asdsaghbnmk777777
3. GeneratedID: ad49kvß4ßfg3ßtß4

Without the 1,2,3... just because of the strange formatting here.

But how? ^^ I tried vbNewLine but it just didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure that `TextBox1.Multiline` is true.

```
TestBox1.AppendText("Generated ID:" & Random() & Environment.NewLine)
```

should work.

Comment: Yeah it did.... I had multiline enabled actually but didn't use AppendText xD Thanks for that!